# In C++ is there a way to give error if a function that takes a class type is passed a derived type instead?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to give an error if a function that takes a class type is passed a derived type instead?
Couldn't find a duplicate of this, perhaps because polymorphism is at the heart of C++.  Example:

```
class Base
{
    int a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
};

int MySpecialFunc(Base &_a) // I want an error/not compile if 'Derived' is passed instead of 'Base'
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is your real question? No, not the one you asked, but the real question to which you believe the solution is this kind of a compilation or a runtime check, and that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to [block deriving from the class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)? The other possibilities I can think of imply abuse of polymorphism.

Comment: Use `private` or `protected` inheritance.   As long as `MySpecialFunc()` is not a member of `Derived`, not a `friend` of `Derived`, and not a member of a `friend` of `Derived`, than passing a `Derived` to `MySpecialFunc()` will not compile.     If you have to use `public` inheritance AND prevent passing a `Derived` to `MySpecialFunc()` then your design is flawed, and you need to redesign to avoid that need.

Answer (score 7):

You could do an exact type check at runtime with [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

However, I would seriously question the underlying motivation for this kind of check.  People often recommend that inheritance be consistent with the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

What you're proposing is that even when a derived class is perfectly Liskov-substitutable for the base class, this function is going to second-guess that substitutability.  It will almost certainly limit extensibility of the base class.

```
int MySpecialFunc(Base& a)
{
    if (typeid(a) != typeid(Base)) 
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Type is not exactly `Base`.");
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is `typeid()` exact? I was under the impression it could return the same result for two slightly different types?

Comment: I think it's exact for polymorphic types.  The [cppreference description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp) for `std::type_info::operator ==()` is:  "Checks if the objects refer to the same types.".  That said, we should try to find the official language in the standard, rather than rely on cppreference.

Comment: I'm trying to find a reference to why I got the impression that it's not to be trusted right now. :-)

Comment: @NicholasM Section `[expr.typeid]` in N4849 (C++20 working draft) says "When typeid is applied to a glvalue whose type is a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a std::type_info object representing the type of the most derived object (that is, the dynamic type) to which the glvalue refers." with slightly different but similar phrasing in N4741.

Comment: @alirakiyan, given the C++ compilation model, it’s hard to see how a compile-time detection could be achieved with this function signature. Obviously with templates it’s straightforward to do. But if the function takes a reference, it might be compiled long before it’s called with a derived type.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you need to limit only a finite set of types, and you only need to prevent passing directly, then overloading would work:

```
int MySpecialFunc(Derived &) = delete;
```

It is possible to get around the restriction with a static cast of the reference though.

Comment: You should be able to use a template to avoid enumerating all the derived types.